# Why does the lubridate::ymd_hms function add an NA observation when the "silent" argument is set TRUE?

Tags: r, lubridate

Could any one explain why the "silent=T" argument triggers a warning and an NA observation, and tell me how to avoid this?

```
x <- c("2010-04-14-04-35-59", "20100401120000")
ymd_hms(x, silent=T)
[1] "2010-04-14 04:35:59 UTC" "2010-04-01 12:00:00 UTC" NA                       

Warning message:
1 failed to parse.
```

R version 3.4.0, lubridate version 1.6.0

Comment: `silent` is not an argument of `ymd_hms`. Do you want `ymd_hms(x, quiet = TRUE)` ?

Comment: Ah - sorry - ofcourse - thank you

Answer (score 2):

Here, lubridate tries to evaluate `"silent=T"` as a date format, the argument for removing message being quiet.

```
lubridate::ymd_hms(x, quiet=TRUE)
[1] "2010-04-14 04:35:59 UTC" "2010-04-01 12:00:00 UTC"
```

This is because you can pass vector inside a lubridate function :

```
x <- c("2010-04-14-04-35-59", "20100401120000")
y <- c("2010-04-14-04-35-59", "20100401120000")
z <- c("2010-04-14-04-35-59", "20100401120000")

lubridate::ymd_hms(x, y, z)
[1] "2010-04-14 04:35:59 UTC" "2010-04-01 12:00:00 UTC"
[3] "2010-04-14 04:35:59 UTC" "2010-04-01 12:00:00 UTC"
[5] "2010-04-14 04:35:59 UTC" "2010-04-01 12:00:00 UTC"
```

So here, with `silent=T`, you're telling lubridate that `silent=T` is a vector to parse. Hence the NA.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue for cases where the format is different. Please see that all the dates are following the same format. Using `parse_date_time()` can solve this problem.

```
parse_date_time(df$date, c("y/m/d","y/m/d HMS","m/d/y","m/d/y HM"))
```

Please be sure that the date format is contained in the list.